# implement SDWebImage in modal segue in Objective-C(iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

I'm currently working on for my thesis in iOS
I'm making a table view and retrieve the data from my own web service,
after retrieving the data, im passing that data from current row to a new modal view for a detail view (summary view to detail view)
for a note, i can't use the push segue because im already have an navigation controller from SWRevealViewController, the real question is when im getting data from my web service (and its working, i can see my image url in NSLOG) and then use sdwebimage set image with url, the image dont download, there's no incoming network connection from what i see in debug view, here's my code
TableView.m file

```
- (void) retrieveData{
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@getDataURL];
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];



JSONArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

//set up array objek wisata
ObjekwisataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//loop jsonArray
for (int i = 0; i < JSONArray.count; i++)
{
    //add objek wisata
    //IdObjek,NamaObjek,DeskripsiObjek,FotoObjek,Latitude,Longitude
    NSString * IdObj = [[JSONArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"idobjek"];
    NSString * NamaObj = [[JSONArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"nama"];
    NSString * DeskripsiObj = [[JSONArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"deskripsi"];
    NSString * FotoObj = [[JSONArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"foto"];
    NSString * LatObj = [[JSONArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"latitude"];
    NSString * LongObj = [[JSONArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"longitude"];


    //untuk gambar


    //add objek wisata ke array objekwisatarray
    [ObjekwisataArray addObject:[[ObjectWisata alloc]initWithNama:NamaObj andDeskripsi:DeskripsiObj andFoto:FotoObj andLatitude:LatObj andLongitude:LongObj andIdObjek:IdObj]];

}

//reload data di table view
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

and this my modal DetailView.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

//load UI
[self setLabels];
[self getWisata:currentWisata];
[self downloadGambar];

NSURL * url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:currentWisata.foto];
[GambarWisata sd_setImageWithURL:url];

NSLog (@"URL FOTO : %@" , [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url]);

/*
NSURL * url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[currentWisata valueForKey:@"foto"]];
NSURL * temp = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:currentWisata.foto];
//[ImageView sd_setImageWithURL:url];
//NSString * temp = url.absoluteString;
//[ImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:temp]];
[GambarWisata sd_setImageWithURL:temp];

//logfile
NSLog (@"VALUE URL : %@" , [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url]);
NSLog (@"VALUE TEMP : %@" , [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",temp]);
*/
backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(backButton)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

}

its actually working when im using only url, in my main view for an opening image, but again, its not working in modal view segue, thanks for your help

Comment: Your problem does not become clear. "its not working" is not a sufficient problem description. If you have problems with your english, try to write shorter sentences, start every sentence with a capital letter and finish it with a full stop. That would already help others understand your text better.

Comment: its doesn't actually convert url to image like i did when im not using an array in my main view

Comment: So what does it do instead? Make coffee? Better describe what you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Comment: well codo, it do nothing instead of convert url into image like it actually did..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so after i checked again, my url link didn't contain an "http://www." prefix, so i'd managed to do it, here's my code :

```
    NSString *urlString = currentWisata.foto;
NSURL *webpageUrl;

if ([urlString hasPrefix:@"http://"] || [urlString hasPrefix:@"https://"]) {
    webpageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
} else {
    webpageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.%@", urlString]];
}
```

Case closed now :)